# How to create a secret key based on a string in RC4 java using libraries

Tags: java, rc4-cipher

This the code to create a random secret key, but I am wondering, is there a way to create one based on a string like "hello"?

```
KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("RC4");
SecretKey k = kg.generateKey();
```

Comment: Why that ? How will you benefit from it ?

Comment: its homework, i have to do it